# Absolute positioning inside absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 `div` elements.

1st `div` is bigger (wrap) and has `position:relative;`

2nd `div` is positioned absolute to the 1st `div` relative positioning (and is included in the 1st `div`)

3rd `div` is contained in the 2nd `div` and also has absolute positioning.

```
<div id="1st">
   <div id="2nd">
     <div id="3rd"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Why is the 3rd `div` position absolute to the 2nd `div` (which is also absolute position to the 1st `div`) and not to 1st `div` that has relative position ?

Because the 3rd `div` is absolute positioning to the absolute positioned 2nd `div`.

Comment: That is really something what i'am looking for and these answers for your questions made my eyes open :\.

Comment: absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Because `position: absolute` resets the relative position for children just as `position: relative` does.

There is no way around this - if you want the third `div` to be absolutely positioned relatively to the first one, you will have to make it a child of the first one.

Comment: So basically the absolute position become relative position for it's absolute positioned child ?

Comment: @pufos kind of. The `0px / 0px` position for children gets reset by the `position: absolute`

Comment: @pufos I think you're confusing this a little. `position:relative` means that element will be positioned (using top, right, bottom left) relatively from its current position. `position: absolute` means it will be positioned relative to browsers window or first parent with `position: absolute` or `position: relative`.

Comment: Can you share a reference to this online ? Because i couldn't find any ... And ... Thanks a lot

Comment: @pufos the very basic reference is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position

Comment: @seler - that's a really succinct way to explain that

Answer (score 32):

Both `position:relative` and `position:absolute` establish containing elements as positioning ascestors.

If you need div 3 to be positioned based on div 1 then make it a direct child of div 1.

Note that `position: relative` means the element is positioned relative to its **natural** position and `position: absolute` means the element is positioned relative to its **first `position:relative` or `position:absolute` ancestor**.

Comment: I wanted the 3rd div to be absolute positioned to the absolute positioned div but i did't know if this is standard (crossbrowser) .. and i couldn't find specifications online ... Thanks a lot

Comment: Absolute positioning in that section: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe absolute means element is positioned relative to its first position:fixed also

Answer (score 15):

**Position static:** the static position is the default way an element
will appear in the normal flow of your
HTML file if no position is specified at all.

Important: `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties HAVE NO EFFECT ON A STATICALLY
POSITIONED ELEMENT.

**Position relative:** positioning an element with the relative value keeps the element (and the space it occupies) in the normal flow of your HTML file.

You can then move the element by some amount using the properties `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`. However, this may cause the element to overlap other elements that are on the
page—which may or may not be the effect that you want.

A relatively positioned element can move from its spot, but the space it occupied remains.

**Position absolute:** applying the absolute position value to an element removes it from the normal flow. When you move the absolute positioned element, its reference point is the top/left of its nearest containing element that has a position declared other than static—also called its nearest positioning context. So, if no containing element with a position other than static exists, then it will be positioned from the top-left corner of
the body element.

In your case 3rd's nearest containing container is 2nd.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another clarifying answer.

Your current scenario is this:

```
#my-parent {position: absolute}
#my-parent .my_child {position: absolute}
```

And you're kind of struggling with it.

If you can change the HTML, simply do this:

```
#my-parent {position: absolute}
#my-parent .my-wrapper {position: relative}        /* Since you've added the wrapper in HTML */
#my-parent .my-wrapper .my-child {position: absolute}  /* Now you can play with it */
```

Comment: my-wrapper probably should be .my-wrapper

Comment: This approach is amazing, I still have no idea why it solved my problem. My problem is that I can't have my third element to be child of the first element due to some other reason.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the 3rd `div` element is absolutely positioned to the 2nd `div` element is because as the CSS spec explains [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Containing_blocks), is because the "parent" element (better said: containing block) of an **absolutely** positioned element **is not** necessarily its immediate parent element, but rather its immediate **positioned** element i.e. any element whose position is set to anything but `static` for example `position: relative/absolute/fixed/sticky;`

Hence, whenever possible in your code, if you want the 3rd `div` element be absolutely positioned in regards to the 1st `div` you should make your 2nd `div` element as `position: static;` which is its default value (or just simply remove any `position: ...` declaration in the rule set of your 2nd `div` element).

The above will make the 1st `div` the **containing block** of the 3rd absolutely positioned `div`, ignoring the 2nd `div` for this positioning purpose.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what you mentioned, [here exact url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block), thanks this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer to this.

I was able to achieve this result by adding a `clear: both;` style to the first absolutely positioned div which reset the child and allowed it to use it's own `absolute` positioning.