# override overflow hidden css property in child div?

Tags: html, css

How to do that? I'd like to make the child div visible when parent div have overflow:hidden property...

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/qDVvC/33/

html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="container" id="hidden">
        <div id="test">totototot</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 #parent {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:10px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .container {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
    }
    #hidden {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #hidden div {
        border:1px solid blue;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        position:absolute;
        top:90%;
        left:-10%;
    }
    #test {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Why you want to use `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: I need it with the configuration of my page... The code here is a simple sample

Comment: Well, than I would like to say that what you are attempting is not possible

Comment: Why must it be a child of the element?  Put it in `#parent` instead.

Comment: Ok, I will try something else... Thanks

Comment: Does the container have to be `position: absolute`?

Comment: yes! But it doesn't seem to override the overflow property

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about `#test`. You should take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5928059/2129835. But if you remove `position: absolute` on `.container` and set it's height/width to `100%` I think you'll get the result you want.

Comment: Mmmh... I think I'll use an other way to do that, I've some other problems and I must change my minds... :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow specific tag to override overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden)