# CSS positioning of DIVs (absolute within relative)

Tags: css, html

In class we learned that if I have two divs: a wrapper div (let's call it div `A`) that's defined as `position: relative;` and another div, div `B` that's inside div `A` with `position: absolute;`.

What will happen is that now the position of div `B` is dependent on the position of div `A`. Meaning that now the point 0,0 of div `B` is not the point 0,0 of the browser, but of div `A`. So, if I was to move div `A` say 20 pixels to the right, and div `B` 30 pixels to the right, div `B` would be 50 pixels to the right of the browser's point 0,0;

Now, my question is: what if I have 3 divs. Div A that's `position: relative;`, within it div `B` that's `position: absolute`, and within div `B`, another div (div `C`) with `position: absolute;`. Now, how will div C behave? Will its position 0,0 be that of div `A` or div `B`?

Thanks in advance.

code:

```
<style type = "text/css">
#a {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
}

#b {
position:absolute;
left: 20px
}

#c {
left: 20px
position:absolute;
}
</style>
<div id = "a">
    <div id = "b">
        <div id = "c">
        test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute positioning inside absolute position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928059/absolute-positioning-inside-absolute-position)

Comment: Note that in your rule for #c above you are missing a semicolon after 20px, which makes the rule fail.

Answer (score 16):

As you can see from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cDQEK/), the position of "C" div is relative to its father "B" with

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't have much to add to both these great answers, but here's an article that helped me understand the concept. http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

### EDIT:

That article covers that a div with position absolute is positioned on the inner grid of its closest ancestor(parent, grandparent, etc.) that is fixed, relative, or absolute.  If there is none it is relative to the html document, but note it still behaves differently than fixed.  It also covers the key differences between the three position types as well as the static position type.

**static** - this is the default position it creates no grids for children absolute positioned divs. You can't use the css properties `top` `left` `right` or `bottom`.

**relative** - creates a grid for descendent(children, grandchildren, etc.) absolute positioned divs. You can use top, left, right and bottom, but they move it 'relative' to where it was previously at. When using top, left, right, and bottom other elements still go around where it was previously at.

**absolute** -  creates a grid for descendent(children, grandchildren, etc.) absolute positioned divs.  You can use top, left, right and bottom, but they move it relative to the closest ancestor(parent, grandparent, etc.) grid. Remember the grids are created by fixed, absolute, and relative elements. When using top, left, right, and bottom the element goes out of the flow of the document. (this means other items go through it.)

**fixed** - creates a grid for children absolute positioned divs. You can use top, left, right and bottom but they move it relative to the browser. When using top, left, right and bottom goes out of the flow of the document. (this means other items go through it.)

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. At the very least please consider what happens if that link becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 6):

Div B - any absolutely positioned element is positioned according to it's **closest positioned (absolute, relative, or fixed) parent**.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of personal preference, but this article was the one that cleared things up even more for me than the AListApart one: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. At the very least please consider what happens if that link becomes unavailable.