# Responsive Menu Pushed into Footer when Footer Position = Absolute

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, footer

I am attempting to hold my footer div at the bottom of the site to avoid blank space underneath it on shorter pages. When I set the position of the footer to be absolute, the responsive menu button seems to take its position relative to the footer and no longer to the header. When I change it back from absolute it works normally. It is almost as if it is associating itself with the footer menu rather than the header menu, but I can see no good reason why this would happen. Also, when I am logged in to WordPress, the top menu bar (on the front end) gets pushed down in just the same way. However, this doesn't happen until the viewport hits 600px (I have no media queries at 600px). The responsive menu already appears at a viewport width of 767px.

This is a WordPress website in progress [here](http://davejudd.com/client/Sri/donate/).

I am using a custom theme and [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/) responsive menu

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on there? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to move the #click-menu div & the #responsive-menu div outside of the footer element in order to fix this.

Here's a similar issue w/ some great answers: [Absolute positioning inside absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928059/absolute-positioning-inside-absolute-position)

Comment: Thank you, you've helped me make perfect sense of the situation. However, I do not know enough about WordPress to understand how the plugin's view is placed specifically in my footer, and how I can change that. Can you enlighten me?